# Laravel trying to get user id to store into posts table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, array(
       'title' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
       'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:articles,slug',
       'category_id' => 'required|integer',
       'content' => 'required|min:2'
   ));

   $article = new Article;
   $article->title = $request->title;
   $article->slug = $request->slug;
   $article->category_id = $request->category_id;

   $article->content = $request->content;
   $article->save();

   Session::flash('success', 'Your article has been published.');
   return redirect()->route('article.show', $article->id);
}
```

There is a user_id column on the articles table,

This is my store function but when I create the post I am looking for a way to store the logged in user id to the user_id column in the articles table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `auth`ed user.

```
$article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$article->save();
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that at first but I didn't include Auth in the namespace how silly of me, alright now I want to extract the name of that user id, how can I do so like when I am on the articles page I can only output $article->user_id, how can i get the name of that id?

Comment: You need to create a relationship from `Article` to `User`, add in your `Article`: `public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }` , then you can get `User` object from `Article` object by: `$article->user->name` :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Also I have a question, I am trying to integrate user privileges how can I come about doing that? I want normal users to just be able to create articles, and admin such as myself to create categories, and such, I already have the categories set up just need to restrict it to myself/admin users only.

Comment: use Laravel Authorization/Policies.

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
$article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

It will store the authenticated user id in the `user_id` field of your article table.

In your case change your Store code to

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, array(
       'title' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
       'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:articles,slug',
       'category_id' => 'required|integer',
       'content' => 'required|min:2'
   ));

   $article = new Article;
   $article->title = $request->title;
   $article->slug = $request->slug;
   $article->category_id = $request->category_id;
   //it will store the current logged in user id in user_id field
   $article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

   $article->content = $request->content;
   $article->save();

   Session::flash('success', 'Your article has been published.');
   return redirect()->route('article.show', $article->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

But there is another method without using even the name space and all.

You can just fix this with the following code:

```
$article->user_id =  auth()->user()->id;
```

instead of:

```
$article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```